# Cannot resize windows remoting-in through X11VNC?

Tags: centos, rhel, x11, gnome

I am remoting on to a Linux box (CentOS 6) using X11VNC. However, I cannot resize any windows manually by hovering over the frame, because the frame resize cursor does not appear.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried resizing the windows anyway despite the fact that the mouse cursor is not the correct one?